# Force empty plot to show up with `patchwork` with pdf_output R Markdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, whitespace, patchwork

I would like to display a single plot that takes up half of my page (to appear like it is taking up one column), using the `patchwork` library and the `plot_spacer()` function. The thing is, I can't get the "empty plot" to take up half the space! No matter what I do, the first plot seems to take up most of the page. I'm looking for the equivalent of `p1 + p2` below, except I'd want `p2` to be white space.

#### Reproducible example and output

```
---
title: " "
author: " "
date: " "
output: pdf_document
geometry: paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in,left=0.4in, right=0.4in, top=0.25in, bottom=0.25in
header-includes:
    - \pagenumbering{gobble}
---

{r, fig.height = 1.5}
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot() + geom_blank()
p3 <- p2 + theme_void()

p1 + plot_spacer()
p1 + p1
p1 + p2
p1 + p3
```

[image: various plots that don't do what I want]

Also note that the plots appear to work in my R session but not when output to pdf:

[image: pics from R session]

Finally, I also tried another suggestion to use `plot_layout`:

```
design <- "
1#
"

p1 + plot_layout(design = design)
```

This also seems to work in the session but not in pdf_output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should set `out.height="50%"` in your code chunk. This means that the plots will take 50% of the page. To create a white space plot, I used a `theme` with white background. You can see this in the code below:

````
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\newpage

```{r, out.height="50%"}
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) + geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot() + geom_blank() + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white', colour = 'white'))
p3 <- p2 + theme_void()

p1 + plot_spacer()
p1 + p1
p1 + p2
p1 + p3
```
````

In the pdf document you will see that the plots will plot 50% of the page. The output of `p1 + plot_spacer()` looks like this:

[image]

Output of `p1 + p1` and `p1 + p2`:

[image]

And finally the output of `p1 + p3`:

[image]

As you can see from the images, the plots are half of the pages in a one column.

Comment: Hi @Quinten, unfortunately your solution doesn't work for me when I output to pdf. Also I want to plots to take up 50% of the page width-wise, not height-wise.

Comment: But I did get a clue! When I deleted the geometry argument from the YAML, it worked as expected. Further experimentation required!